# how to create add a git repo as submodule after its created locally first

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following

```
project_main
--test1.txt
--text2.txt
--.git
--new_folder  <-- currently its local repo
  --test1.txt
  --text2.txt
  --.git
```

Now in the `new_folder` I did

```
# inside new_folder
git add remote git:someurl
git add -A; git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Now how to add the `new_folder` as a `submodule` to the `project_main`

Generally we add submodule using (i.e getting some remote repo)

```
git submodule add -- git://someurl new_folder
```

but here I want a newly created repo to be added as submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `new_folder` out of the parent repo and create a separate repo for that and push. Then,

```
cd project_main
git submodule add --name new_folder file:///path/to/new_folder
git add new_folder/
git commit -m 'new_folder is a submodule'
```

Comment: other than that there is no easy solution then